# How would I insert a JavaScript variable into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do something like this:

```
<span class="scoreboard">Your score is ${score}</span>
```

and then have javascript like this:

```
let score;
// do score stuff
```

Basically have dynamic HTML.
I googled this but didn't find anything relevant.
I have this right now

```
function draw() {
  // ignore this game.screen.innerHTML = "";
  // and this tilemap.map.forEach(elem => game.screen.innerHTML += `${elem}<br>`);
  game.scoreboard.innerHTML = `Score: ${player.collected}`;
}
```

this is mostly personal preference so I understand that its irrelevant

Comment: [Start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)

Comment: This is only really possible using template languages which compile to JS/HTML. Like Mustache, handlebars, JSX, etc.

Comment: could you elaborate @evolutionxbox I want to know

Comment: Tools like the ones I've already mentioned usually introduce an extra build step before producing the final HTML/JS. This is if you don't want server-side rendered code, like PHP, node, C#, etc. People use libraries like react if they need client-side reactive template code.

Comment: Can you share `tilemap` object

Comment: @manikantgautam why does it need to be shared?

Comment: @evolutionxbox bcz you are using map however not using it in a way which rings crazy

Comment: @manikantgautam sorry, I didn't write the question. The reason I asked is because I didn't think the question was about the map since the code is commented out saying "ignore".

Comment: if its a array of string `map` is not required

Comment: that is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
let score = 5;
document.querySelector('span.scoreboard').innerText = `Your score is ${score}`;
```

You need something more than HTML to create dynamic content.

Comment: a way to do it in the HTML only? if this is the only way im fine its just personal preference here

Comment: You can't handle variables in HTML in the way I think you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```js
let score;
// do score stuff
document.querySelector(".scoreboard").innertText = `Your score is ${score}`;
```

Comment: I know that but I want to do it in cleaner way